# How to add a curtain on top of the google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need the title to research and not sure what suitable in this case, the google map is annoying and it will crash the entire design of the website. may i know how could i make a curtain or image-like on top of the embeded google map, when user hover the image will slide up and showing the google map ?

Thank you for reply

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have tried to place a `<div>` over the top of the map using jQuery to slide the curtain up?

This slides the wrong way, but you get the idea in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VF57B/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="curtain"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map{
    background-image: url('http://0.tqn.com/d/webtrends/1/0/e/2/-/-/google-maps-walk-2.jpg');
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
}

#curtain{
    background-image: url('http://www.vectordiary.com/isd_tutorials/005_curtain/step02_2.gif');
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:-400px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#curtain').click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp("slow");
});
```

Comment: yep =D but what should be the keyword for that thing ??

Comment: Thx dude !! This is what i want and i can mod it to the version i want =D Thank you ~

Comment: By the way, the reason the curtain falls the wrong way is because of the css margin:-400px, the slideUp() call is telling the div to increase its margin until it gets to 0 (hence why it would go the wrong way), slideDown() may work. If you are getting stuck, look into these areas.